# Get SID without wmic via cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic, sid

I'm using the windows 1709 OS. But this windows does not have `whoami` or `wmic` in it.
Is there any other way to get the user SID via the cmd?

Comment: You can use Sysinternals `psgetsid` to look up the SID of `%username%`.

Comment: But `whoami` and `wmic` are available in Windows 10. If your installation is missing them, who knows what else is missing. I suggest you try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

## Details:

Commands used in solution: for, whoami, findstr, echo.....all native in the OS, and no use of WMIC.

## Cmd:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %A in ('whoami /all ^| findstr /i %username%') do @echo %A
```

## Output:

```
S-1-5-21-277974881-2357446463-7727422770-1002
```